# Page width exceeding the width of browser window.Using html and css

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/WJywf/

i am getting that extra side width . dont know what causing it.tried developer tools .
Page width is more than the browser window , tried changing background width

```
body,
html {
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px white;
 margin: 0px;
 min-height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.backgrnd{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: -9999;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 background: url('../Img/bg2.jpg') no-repeat;
 filter: blur(10px);
 background-size: cover;
}
.container {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 }

.content {
  padding-bottom: 75px;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: try `height: calc(100% - 75px);` in `.content` If that doesn't work, please paste your html structure or a JSFiddle example

Comment: FYI, background-size is used to layout background not html

Comment: @singe31 http://jsfiddle.net/WJywf/

Comment: This is likely due to bad html. I just opened the html and a lot of tags do not match up correctly. Still looking at it. Might set you in the right direction in the mean time.

Comment: thats coz i have removed php coding from it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.search` class have width 100% and margin-left 10%. That cause the issue. Update your `.search` class like below.

```
.search {
float: left;
margin-left: 10%;
width: 90%;
display: block;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much .. it worked .. i wasted my 3 hours but didnt looked their .. thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

Always remember Margin and padding both take space form the main width so if you have a div in which you want to give margin 10% then the width of div should be 90 %.

CSS :- update your search class

```
.search {
float: left;
margin-left: 10%;
width: 90%;
display: block;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```